# incandescent bulbs on Christmas light string allowed?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

Is connecting 6.0 V and 2.5 V incandescent bulbs on same light string allowed? In a 50 light bulb string I like to put two 6.0V bulbs and cut off 5 light sockets.
The total voltage in the string will be 19.5V.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to mix voltage ratings in Xmas bulbs. Just one 'alien' bulb can significantly alter the voltages and currents in the remaining ones.

Comment: Yes it is "allowed" (it is not illegal) **however** 1) some lights might burn brighter than others 2) some lights will **burn out** sooner because of this change. When you do not use the same type and model lightbulbs as recommended by the manufacturer everywhere in the chain then the lightbulbs will not all get the same voltage so some of them will have a shorter lifetime. So allowed: yes, but not a good idea.

Comment: If all your bulbs draw the same amount of current and the total bulb voltage rating (or drop) is equal to your supply voltage, then yes you can connect them in series within reason.